# How do I separate OpenLayers methods from my own, while using inheritance?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am working on a GIS API, that uses OpenLayers. I initialize the map lke this:

```
xgis.map = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Map, {
    var mapOptions = {};
    mapOptions.allOverlays = false;
    /*
        more mapOptions here
    */
    OpenLayers.Map.prototype.initialize.apply(this, ['map', mapOptions]);
});
```

Of course, I do this because I want to create my own methods, like this one, for example.

```
xgis.map.prototype.zoom(action) {
    switch(action) {
        case 'in:
            this.zoomIn();    // Uses the OpenLayers zoomIn method
            break;
        case 'out:
            this.zoomOut();    // Uses the OpenLayers zoomOut method
            break;
};
```

The problem is this 'zoom' method I created is not recognized as a function (I get: number is not a function), because OpenLayers has a 'zoom' numeric value where it stores the zoom.

Is there a way to use inheritance and access the parent's methods like this?

```
this.parent.zoomIn()
```

This would definitely fix the 'zoom' name problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing bad, it must be:

```
xgis.map.prototype.zoom = function(action) { ... }
```

Anyway, it is better you follow the Ol code conventions. To create subclasses you must create methods inside  class definition, something like:

```
xgis.map = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Map, {
    someAttribute: 'someValue'.
    someMethod: function() {
        ...
    }

    CLASS_NAME: 'your_class_name'
});
```

You can find a custom control code at: http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/recipes/ch08/crossControl.js
Which is part of the samples of the [OpenLayers Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/openlayers-cookbook). See more samples at http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/ the sample "chapter8-custom control".